# How to access a custom logger, from a VS breakpoint action, in an external assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, breakpoints

## Background

Visual studio has a really cool feature in that allows you to log a message to the output window when a breakpoint is hit.  Even more cool, you can reference live values by surrounding them with curly brackets.  But wait: there's more; you can even call a method, with arbitrary signature (passing arguments and returning a value).  Whatever value is returned is written in the output window. Awsome.

In VS 2013, this is the "When Hit" feature 
[image]
and in VS 2015 (and 2017 RC), it's called "Action".
[image: ![![enter image description here]

## Motivation

I am trying to understand what's going on in the WPF source code, so I set breakpoints with an "Action" to output trace info. But, because WPF is not constraining the types of the values I'm interested in (they are passed as `object` and the type inferred according to context), the values are more often than not logged as an error because the breakpoint Action is not aware of this context and therefore not aware of the type to expect.

My plan to deal with this is to call a custom logger from the breakpoint Action and pass arguments sufficient for the logger can resolve the type of the value.
The custom logger is a member of my MainWindow partial class.

## Proof of concept

I verified that this works by setting a breakpoint action in my MainWindow partial class, it references the logger member and passes arguments no problem.  This is fine for breakpoints within my app but I want to use it on breakpoints in other assemblies.

## The problem

As stated above, this works fine when the breakpoint is in my own assembly but fails for breakpoints set in third party assemblies (like the wpf source code). Obviously the object needs to be qualified so that the debugger can resolve it.

How do I qualify it, how do I reference the instance of the window and therefore the member I'm looking for?
I guess I could make it a static singleton but I might need more than one logger.

Comment: From what I managed to understand you want to write logs from an assembly you don`t own its source code? (I dont mean .pdb files, I mean .cs files)

Comment: It's the wpf source code. I have the pdbs so I can't set breakpoints and I added an ini file to switch off optimization, so I can step through the code. I guess I need to understand what context the debugger sees and how to address my own logger class (which is instantiated on my main window) from there.

Comment: Sorry... you can only step through. You cannot change the code in any manner without the source files, not even for debugging. If they have there own logger in the code maybe you can use it instead.

Comment: I'm not interested in changing the source code, I'm using a feature in VS debugger as per the pic in my question. It's the debugger that calls the logger, not the code I'm stepping through.

Comment: And yet it is in the same context. You cannot. If you have the PDB files you can set the breakpoints (once you stepped into the "source code", and then you can write to the output window which is as close as you get.

Comment: Hmm, ok. By the way, can you provide a link to a knowledge source where it is documented about the context? Also, are you certain there is no way to reference my own code in the debug environment if so, can you provide a link for that also?

Comment: Sorry again... English is not my native language so some times I pick the wrong words. By context I meant that it is the same that you cannot change the source code even if you call from the visual studio debugger. I don`t think it is written anywhere.

Comment: Ok, thanks for taking the time to explain. Again, I'm not tying to change anything in the assemblies that I don't own, I'm just trying to reference my own Logger method, from the Action feature on a breakpoint, as in the pic. This works fine if the bp is in my own assembly but not if the bp is set in the 3rd party assy. I'm trying to figure out if maybe I need to fully qualify my Logger method and if so, how.

Comment: @shahareldad, in case you are interested, I tried to make the question a bit clearer but anyway, I figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that I can reference my logger.  For example, if my main window partial class looks like this...

```
namespace EventSetterNull_SO_41604891_2670182
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
```

...then I can reference it like this...

```
((EventSetterNull_SO_41604891_2670182.MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow)
```

So, my breakpoint is like...
[image]

Then, I can set breakpoints in, for example, System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes, pass the xamlReader to my logger, and log out the node structure that the parser generates from the baml.

### xaml

```
<Window x:Class="EventSetterNull_SO_41604891_2670182.BuildInXaml"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EventSetterNull_SO_41604891_2670182"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="BuildInXaml" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SetterBaseCollection x:Key="ButtonStyleSetters">
            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Height" Value="30"></Setter>
        </SetterBaseCollection>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Button Name="Button1"
            local:Behaviours.StyleSetters="{StaticResource ButtonStyleSetters}" />
```

### Output window

```
"Line:    6    NamespaceDeclaration    http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
"Line:    6    NamespaceDeclaration    http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
"Line:    6    NamespaceDeclaration    http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
"Line:    6    NamespaceDeclaration    http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
"Line:    6    NamespaceDeclaration    clr-namespace:EventSetterNull_SO_41604891_2670182;assembly=EventSetterNull-SO-41604891-2670182"
"Line:    6    StartObject    BuildInXaml" 
"Line:    6        StartMember    Title"
"Line:    6            Value    BuildInXaml"
"Line:    6        EndMember    "
"Line:    8        StartMember    Height"
"Line:    8            Value    System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension"
"Line:    8        EndMember    "
"Line:    8        StartMember    Width"
"Line:    8            Value    System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension"
"Line:    8        EndMember    "
"Line:    8        StartMember    Resources"
"Line:    9            GetObject    System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext"
"Line:    9                StartMember    DeferrableContent"
"Line:    9                    Value    System.IO.MemoryStream"
"Line:    9                EndMember    "
"Line:    9            EndObject    "
"Line:   15        EndMember    "
"Line:   17        StartMember    Content"
"Line:   17            StartObject    Button" 
"Line:   17                StartMember    ConnectionId"
"Line:   17                    Value    1"
"Line:   17                EndMember    "
"Line:    0                StartMember    Name"
"Line:    0                    Value    Button1"
"Line:    0                EndMember    "
"Line:   17                StartMember    StyleSetters"
"Line:   17                    Value    System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension"
"Line:   17                EndMember    "
"Line:   10                StartObject    SetterBaseCollection" 
"Line:   10                    StartMember    _Items"
"Line:   11                        StartObject    Setter" 
"Line:   11                            StartMember    Property"
"Line:   11                                Value    Height"
"Line:   11                            EndMember    "
"Line:   11                            StartMember    Value"
"Line:   11                                Value    30"
"Line:   11                            EndMember    "
"Line:   11                        EndObject    "
"Line:   11                    EndMember    "
"Line:   11                EndObject    "
"Line:   18            EndObject    "
"Line:   18        EndMember    "
"Line:   18    EndObject    "
```

So, I can see exactly how wpf sees the xaml, which is handy if it screws up...

### xaml

```
<Window x:Class="EventSetterNull_SO_41604891_2670182.BuildInXaml"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EventSetterNull_SO_41604891_2670182"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="BuildInXaml" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SetterBaseCollection x:Key="ButtonStyleSetters">
            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Height" Value="30"></Setter>
            <EventSetter Event="ButtonBase.Click"  Handler="StyleClick"
                          HandledEventsToo="False" />
        </SetterBaseCollection>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Button Name="Button1"
            local:Behaviours.StyleSetters="{StaticResource ButtonStyleSetters}" />
```

### Output window

```
"Line:    6    NamespaceDeclaration    http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
"Line:    6    NamespaceDeclaration    http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
"Line:    6    NamespaceDeclaration    http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
"Line:    6    NamespaceDeclaration    http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
"Line:    6    NamespaceDeclaration    clr-namespace:EventSetterNull_SO_41604891_2670182;assembly=EventSetterNull-SO-41604891-2670182"
"Line:    6    StartObject    BuildInXaml" 
"Line:    6        StartMember    Title"
"Line:    6            Value    BuildInXaml"
"Line:    6        EndMember    "
"Line:    8        StartMember    Height"
"Line:    8            Value    System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension"
"Line:    8        EndMember    "
"Line:    8        StartMember    Width"
"Line:    8            Value    System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension"
"Line:    8        EndMember    "
"Line:    8        StartMember    Resources"
"Line:    9            GetObject    System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext"
"Line:    9                StartMember    DeferrableContent"
"Line:    9                    Value    System.IO.MemoryStream"
"Line:    9                EndMember    "
"Line:    9            EndObject    "
"Line:   15        EndMember    "
"Line:   17        StartMember    Content"
"Line:   17            StartObject    Button" 
"Line:   17                StartMember    ConnectionId"
"Line:   17                    Value    1"
"Line:   17                EndMember    "
"Line:    0                StartMember    Name"
"Line:    0                    Value    Button1"
"Line:    0                EndMember    "
"Line:   17                StartMember    StyleSetters"
"Line:   17                    Value    System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension"
"Line:   17                EndMember    "
"Line:   10                StartObject    SetterBaseCollection" 
"Line:   10                    StartMember    _Items"
"Line:   11                        StartObject    Setter" 
"Line:   11                            StartMember    Property"
"Line:   11                                Value    Height"
"Line:   11                            EndMember    "
"Line:   11                            StartMember    Value"
"Line:   11                                Value    30"
"Line:   11                            EndMember    "
"Line:   11                        EndObject    "
"Line:   12                        StartObject    EventSetter" 
"Line:   12                            StartMember    Event"
"Line:   12                                Value    System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension"
"Line:   12                            EndMember    "
"Line:   12                            StartMember    Event"
Exception thrown: 'System.Xaml.XamlDuplicateMemberException' in System.Xaml.dll
```

As you can see, wpf is getting confused and finding a second Event member in the EventSetter object, that's not there and throwing an error.
[image]
This is a bug in wpf.

Comment: @shahareldad the only code to write is `{((EventSetterNull_SO_41604891_2670182.MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).Logger.Log(xamlReader)}` and the logger. You can shorten the reference by right-clicking on the logger in a watch window and selecting Make ObjectId. Then you can use `{$1.Logger.Log(xamlReader)}`. And that will work, but only for the debug session.

Comment: Very nice then. I didn`t knew the feature of ObjectId